# How to use a single modal with form across all components in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular9, angular-ngmodel

*Angular Version :9 (using ngbModal & ngbootstrap)*

I am working on a way to create login & register functionality in my angular application

As of now,
I have the login code inside my NavbarComponent which is visible throughout all other components.

NavbarComponent.ts

```
constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private userService: UserService,
        private sessionService: SessionStorageService,
        private constant: AppConstants,
        private modalService: NgbModal,
      ) {
        this.createLoginForm();
      }     
    
openLoginModal(content: any) {
            this.createLoginForm()
            this.modalService.open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title', backdrop: 'static' 
            }).result.then((result) => {
              this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
              this.login()
            }, (reason) => {
              this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
            });
          }
   
createLoginForm() {
        this.loginform = this.formBuilder.group({
          email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/\S+@\S+\.\S+/)]],
          password: [null, [Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/)]]
        })
      }
```

on modal submit, login method will add data to session storage & everything works

Now, I want people to be able to view the content without login & only need login if they want to add something. Hence, I want this login functionality to be in all my components.

**When user clicks a POST button on some other component, this login modal should be displayed & form submission must happen on login click, nothing else in the existing page should change.**

I could have separate modals in all components but that would immensely violate the **DRY** principle
I researched a lot on this, some suggested to create a different module for it, some suggested a new component. I didn't find anything case specific.

So, after understanding the case what would be the optimal solution for this?

**Edit** :-
*navbar.component.html has a login button. On clicking that, login modal will appear(which has a login form)
I want to open this modal(with form and other features of modal) by clicking the add button which is on some xyz.component.html*

P.S: Thanks for your time. I would also welcome changes on an atomic level if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're importing your navigation component in every module of your application it should then be in a shared module. If that's the case, you should just add a login component wich would be a modal itself. Then with a simple onclick function you open that component.

If it's not in a shared module I would just create a login component and place it in the same module as your navigation. By clicking on login in navigation, your login component would also be availible.

Comment: import as in there is the <nav selector></nav selector> in the html of every component 
Can you explain the sharing with some example code?

Comment: Create a new module named shared, move your nav component in it and then import the shared module in every module required. There's no code to show. In the shared module you create your login compoenent so it's availible when you use your nav component. If your question is how to create a modal, you just have to look at the following links with are the commun librairie used: Angular material - https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview OR ng-bootstrap - https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples OR ngx-bootstrap - https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

Comment: thank you! but I don't have problems with the modal. Please read the edit (maybe I wasn't fully clear about my problem!)
I want to execute the open modal of NavigationComponent from any other component!

Comment: Ye the first answer is right... Create a module which you can import in every module. And that component will have confirm dialog component, your login dialog component and any other component you want to share over all the application...

Comment: You should also think about moving your nav component in that module.

Comment: To import the shared module in any other module, just use the import array in that module: `@NgModule({ imports: [SharedModule]})` I can't give you more then that. Else it would be coding the whole thing. If you don't understand what a module is, you should look the doc -> https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules and if you're not using modules in your application, you should for the lazy-loading https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: Hi leccho, I know the sharing part but what I don't know is this "you should just add a login component wich would be a modal itself. Then with a simple onclick function you open that component." 
So I can have an entire component for a modal which can be opened by other components(with form)?
can you give me some links so I can see the example code or the docs to achieve this!

Comment: When you import the shared module in an other module, all the shared module componenent become availible for use, so you do as if the component was in the same module

Comment: `const modalRef = this.modalService.open(LoginComponent);
 modalRef.componentInstance.loginSuccess.subscribe(() => { /*Action here*/ });`

Comment: The idea worked! Had to find an example. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using Angular CanActivate router Guard. More information can be found on angular site or google.

https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Here is a link that I found on google which might give you some help you.

http://gnomeontherun.com/2017/03/02/guards-and-login-redirects-in-angular/

Comment: yeah, but that is only applicable to routing (I think) 
I want every user to be able to do get operations on all components.
Just need to pop the login modal when he/she tries to do a POST request via some button click.